# Regular expression get the href attribute

Tags: regex, strip-tags

i'm trying to get the href tag from below html code. This just the part of the full html.

```
<div class=\"adr\"><a title=\"8632 Open Meadow Way, Columbia, MD\" href=\"\/homedetails\/8632-Open-Meadow-Way-Columbia-MD-21045\/37058296_zpid\/\">8632 Open Meadow Way, Columbia, MD<\/a><\/div>
```

I have tried many method, but no luck. I'm looking for regular expression.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

```
/href=\\"(.*?)\\"/  //substring should be capture group 1.
```

*edit:* but what if there's a double quote in the data? is it double-double quoted then? then you might try this:

```
/href=\\"(""|.*?)\\"/
```

Comment: Thanks, 
This works for me for above HTML contents. But the actual problem is my HTML contains lots "href" tags(HTML of a wesite), so this regex may have issue.

I want to strip the "href" tag in side the <div class=\"adr\"> tag. Is this possible? please help me.

Answer (score 1):

`href` is not a tag, it's an attribute. Secondly, for all that's holy, don't use regexes to parse HTML, that's what DOM is for. You didn't specify what language you are using, if it's Javascript, the proper function to use is [element.getAttribute()](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_getattribute.asp).

Comment: Thanks, I will explain more,

I'm using PHP to parse the HTML out put of another web page. I have tried DOM method in PHP, but no luck. The main reason is required href attribute is actually commented in the DOM not visible in the UI.

Code is like this,
<!--<div class=\"adr\"><a title=\"8632 Open Meadow Way, Columbia, MD\" href=\"\/homedetails\/8632-Open-Meadow-Way-Columbia-MD-21045\/37058296_zpid\/\">8632 Open Meadow Way, Columbia, MD<\/a><\/div>-->

I guess, that is why my DOM method is not grabbing the HREF attribute. Hope you got what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Surely, just this (with whatever escaping necessary depending on your platform). The key is the minimal-munch quantifier after the *, otherwise it will consume until the last possible quote.

```
a\s+href="(.*?)"
```